# Liferay Session extend (/c/portal/extend_session) - HTTP 403 Forbidden

Tags: tomcat, liferay, liferay-6, tomcat8

I am facing 403 Forbidden exceptions whenever `/c/portal/expire_session` or `/c/portal/extend_session` (and some others) are invoked. This happens regularly even when no user is logged in (since the guest user also retains a session).

I switched off automatic session extension in Liferay on purpose (`session.timeout.auto.extend=false`, `session.timeout.redirect.on.expire=true`).

I am using Liferay 6.2 CE GA5 bundled with Tomcat 8.5. It is more or less a plain setup (no extra filters, just some custom portlets and hooks).

MS Edge Developer console:

```
HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. (XHR)POST - https://xxxxx:8443/c/portal/expire_session
```

Tomcat access logs:

```
[21/Nov/2018:09:23:54 +0100] "POST /c/portal/expire_session HTTP/1.1" 403 -
```

Tomcat connector:

```
                <Connector
                    URIEncoding="UTF-8"
                    connectionTimeout="20000"
                    maxPostSize="20971520"
                    port="8443"
                    protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                    scheme="https"
                    server="May the eHealth Solutions be with you"
                    secure="true"
                    SSLEnabled="true"
                    SSLVerifyClient="none"
                    SSLProtocol="TLSv1.2"
                    SSLCertificateFile="${catalina.home}/conf/localhost.crt"
                    SSLCertificateKeyFile="${catalina.home}/conf/localhost.key"
                    SSLCACertificateFile="${catalina.home}/conf/localhost.crt"
                    SSLHonorCipherOrder="true">
                    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
            </Connector>
```

Any ideas and suggestions highly welcome!

Thx and Cheers
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because I hate unanswered questions:

The Problem was a CORS Filter which checked correctly for `Content-Type` within the request headers.

Liferay's AUI requests do not set this header (funny thing: Its only missing in MS Edge - Could not figure out why yet).

What I do now is setting the header in the prototype of `AUI.IO` like so:

```
AUI().IO.prototype._headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'};
```

Now, the request is not filtered out any more by the CORS filter.

Cheers
Stefan